# Custom cursor on google captcha

Tags: html, css

I have added a google captcha to my register form, but the custom cursor I had added before to both body and g-captcha class does not work. Here is the code:

```
.g-recaptcha
{
    cursor: url(img/misc/pointer.png), pointer; 
}

<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="..."></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with `height` and `width` values. so:

```
cursor: url(image.png) 32 32, auto;
```